# CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile without an associated payment

Tags: paypal

I'm working with Recurring Payments and all I want is this:

1. The user clicks an "authorize" button on my site
2. They are taken to paypal, where they confirm **but don't have to pay anything yet**
3. I get the recurring payment's PROFILEID, TOKEN, or whatever I need so that I can charge them at the end of the month if necessary.

I'm completely lost and PayPal's documentation is NO HELP.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  This has been going on for weeks and I have so many questions that I don't even know which ones to ask.

We tried using Reference Transactions initially but PayPal won't approve our account for Reference Transactions since we don't yet have 90 days of history with them (it's needed for the functionality of our site....go figure).  Talking on the phone with them, they said we can get approved for Reference Transactions -- maybe -- if we put up another one of our businesses' PayPal account as collateral.  We don't like the idea of this, and they suggested using the Billing Agreement button, so we're looking in to that.

The button won't work for us because (1) we need to be able to send bills out automatically, not manually inside PayPal's site, and (2) we need to know automatically whether a user has approved the billing agreement.

So we're dealing with the Recurring Payments API now.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What part of the process is failing for you? I can help you get Recurring Payments and Express Checkout set up but I need a little more detail on what you're hung up on.

I don't know much about the approval process for any product so I can't help there - sorry

Comment: Hi Patrick -- we're approved for ref. transactions now so this is no longer an issue.  When I was working with Recurring Payments the issue was two-fold: recurring payments *require* an initial payment and the payment amt. can not be changed on a per-month basis.  If I'd've known those facts from the start I could've avoided this headache!  Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference transactions are necessary for what you are requesting.

Until then, the best workaround/solution is going to be:

1. Have the customer do a normal 1-time checkout with an
   authorization that you may capture within 29 days (if the funds are
   available; they are only actually reserved for the first 3 days)
2. If/when the time period extends beyond 29 days, send the customer a new PayPal email invoice (either manually or with the invoicing API) to collect payment.

Again, reference transactions (and the associated ability to create EC billing agreements) are going to be your long-term solution, but you must wait for PayPal to approve this on your live account.

For testing purposes in the sandbox, reference transactions must also be enabled on the Business account you're using there.  Contact www.paypal.com/mts for this and include the email of your Business account in the sandbox.

Comment: Ya know, we actually ended up doing exactly what you suggested for a couple of days until this morning, when we were finally approved for reference transactions.  Now we've got our implementation working like a charm!  Thanks for your time